# Error when trying to execute a php script to transfer data in to a mysql that previously worked

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Our company has been running an Android app which allows data to be inputted in to a msql database, It was previously working fine.
We decided we would create a server dedicated to the task rather than just hosting the php files on our usual FTP server, and also to split up the mysql admin so that it wasn't all getting mixed up with the time and attendance databases/tables. 
When moving over the scripts, I re-created the mySql databases/tables but with different names/passwords. 
I changed on the app the link to the php script, and in the php script changed all the connection information (username, Password etc.).

---

Here is what it currently Looks like

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","appuser1","Password","VehicleCheckList");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$RegNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['RegNumber']);
$DriverName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['DriverName']);
$Mileage = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Mileage']);
$Tyres = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Tyres']);
$Windscreen = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Windscreen']);
$Lights = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Lights']);
$Fuel = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Fuel']);
$WarningLights = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['WarningLights']);
$BodyWork = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['BodyWork']);
$Wheels = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Wheels']);
$Oil = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Oil']);
$TyreWear = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['TyreWear']);
$Horn = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Horn']);
$Mirrors = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Mirrors']);
$Cab = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Cab']);
$Boot = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Boot']);
$Seatbelts = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Seatbelts']);
$Noise = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Noise']);
$Comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Comments']);
$Date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Date']);
$Agreement = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Agreement']);
$Initials = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['Initials']);


$sql="INSERT INTO vcform1 (RegNumber, DriverName, Mileage, Tyres, Windscreen, Lights, Fuel, WarningLights, BodyWork, Wheels, Oil, TyreWear, Horn, Mirrors, Cab, Boot, Seatbelts, Noise, Comments, Date, Agreement, Initials)
VALUES ('$RegNumber', '$DriverName', '$Mileage', '$Tyres', '$Windscreen', '$Lights', '$Fuel', '$WarningLights', '$BodyWork', '$Wheels', '$Oil', '$TyreWear', '$Horn', '$Mirrors', '$Cab', '$Boot', '$Seatbelts', '$Noise', '$Comments', '$Date', '$Agreement', '$Initials')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

---

It wont work though, and when I try to run a html form in to the script I get the following error;

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home/appacmefg/public_html/App_Files/VehicleCheckList/vcform1.php on line 2
```

Would anybody be able to help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: mysqli is enabled...? ^^ x)

Comment: You dont have mysqli extension installed/enabled. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Comment: Try to see if you have mysqli extension enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have the MySQLi extension installed. How you install it depends on your OS/distribution. If you use some sort of Linux, your package manager probably has a package for it (i.e. apt-get install php5-mysql; or yum install php-mysql)

For PHP 5.3+ on windows, it should be enabled by default:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php#mysqli.installation.windows